# Generate JSON from two different JSON objects without coding custom logic

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema, json-patch, dotliquid

I have a requirement where an event will emit a JSON following a defined schema = JSON-EventA schema. I have a config(config.json) that follows another JSON-EventB schema. Using data from JSON-EventA and Config from config.json, I have to generate a JSON event data which should follow the JSON-EventB schema.  Is this possible to write a function `GenerateEventData` which takes the eventA data and config to generate EventB data ? Without coding the POCO and writing custom logic to convert from one json to another ? I want to be able to update the JSON-EventA schema, config.json without touching the function `GenerateEventData`, it should be able to generate data in the new JSON-EventB schema as directed by config.json

Illustrating an example that I want -

```
// I can get an event data and ensure it follows JSON-EventA schema
string eventAData = GetEvent(A);
/*
eventAData = {"Title": "MyTitle", "Address": {"PING": "123"}}
Follows the below schema
EventASchema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Address": {
       "type": "object",
       "properties": {
         "PIN": {
          "type": "string"
         }
       }
    }
};*/

string config = GetConfig();
// config = {"NewTitle": "Generated ${Title}", "PIN": "000${Address.PIN}", "Country": "US"}

//This is what I want to achieve.
string eventB = GenerateEventData(A, config);
/*
eventB = {"NewTitle": "Generated MyTitle", "PIN": "000123", "Country": "US"}
*/
```

Comment: "I want to be able to update the JSON-EventA schema, config.json without touching the function" You probably could use JSON to configure the mapping between schema A and schema B. There are probably open source 3rd party solutions for that. But you will still have to update the mapping whenever one of the schemas changes.

Comment: Isn't there any string-templating + json schema based way to do this ?

Comment: I really have no clue. However, I suppose you're not the first nor the last that encountered such a problem, and therefore I suppose there's an already written and tested solution somewhere online, and all you need to do is to find it.

Comment: Finally what I am going with is - EventA is following a specified JSON schema. I am validating that using MIcrosoft jschema library. The GetConfig method provides a template in liquid format which I use with EventA data to generate EventB data.